# How to combined numbered and symbol footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, etoolbox, footmisc

I want to combine both regular and numbered footnotes. Currently I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% search
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{%
     \expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% replace
  {}{}% success/failure
\makeatother

\DeclareFixedFootnote\daggerfoot{Ongoing}
\DeclareFixedFootnote\asteriskfoot{Finished}

\begin{document}

This should be regular footnote\footnote{Regular.}.

\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 1\asteriskfoot
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3\asteriskfoot
\end{itemize}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l l} 
 \hline
 \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Points} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Row 1 & 3 \\
 Row 2\daggerfoot & 4.5 \\
 Row 3\daggerfoot & 3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The problem with it is that the first footnote, which comes from `\footnote{}` part should be displayed as 1, whereas the other footnotes should be symbols as they are at the moment. However, currently also the first footnote is displayed as a symbol. How can I combine numbered and symbol footnotes? Or more like regular footnotes with fixed footnotes.

Comment: How should the footnotes appear in the footer? in order of appearance in on apparatus or split into symbol footnotes and other footnotes?

Comment: @cgnieder Well in my case actually all the symbol footnotes will appear in the last section, so they will come after all the other regular footnotes. So, I found all the footnotes until certain section to be all numbered regular footnotes, and then in the last section I will have fixed symbol footnotes inside itemize and table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the information from your comment:

- don't use the `symbol` option from `footmisc`
- reset the footnote counter before you switch to the fixed ones and redefine `\thefootnote` to use symbols with `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`
- while we're there: if you insist in the `footnote` package you should probably load it after `footmisc`; otherwise `\makesavenoteenv` will complain about the definitions of `\footnote`

The MWE then gives (with reduced paper geometry for an easier demonstration):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.6\textwidth,
  paperheight=22\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% search
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{%
     \expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% replace
  {}{\ERROR}% success/failure
\makeatother

\DeclareFixedFootnote\daggerfoot{Ongoing}
\DeclareFixedFootnote\asteriskfoot{Finished}

\begin{document}

This should be regular footnote\footnote{Regular.}.

\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 1\asteriskfoot
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3\asteriskfoot
\end{itemize}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l l} 
 \hline
 \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Points} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Row 1 & 3 \\
 Row 2\daggerfoot & 4.5 \\
 Row 3\daggerfoot & 3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely!